# Sass and Gulp issues. Sass and Ruby not in PATH

Tags: rubygems, osx-mavericks, gulp

Having serious issues with gulp and the moment. When i run my task it errors saying

```
`You need to have Ruby and Sass installed and in your PATH for this task to work.`
```

Now I have check that I have both ruby and sass install but it still is not working. Anyone else come across this issue. If so please share the wealth of your knowledge.

I have updated everything but this has had no effect. I am using a mac and so assumed ruby was already install.

Thanks in advance

### Update

It appears only to happen when I am using gulp within a wordpress project. I hope this may help somebody fix this issue.

Comment: Have you `gem install sass` ?

Comment: Yes, the gem is installed. Strangley it works on the static projects but not with a wordpress project. It is the same on both my mac and on my windows machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I have solved the riddle.

It turns out it was a problem with Foundation. I had update my version of sass and this was not compatible with foundation but this type of error was suppressed. I was using a different version of foundation for my wordpress projects and so that is why it was only causing a problem there. Very annoying!!